# Publishing to Azure Mobile Service with Lets Encrypt certificate gives Runtime Error

Tags: azure-mobile-services, lets-encrypt

I have set up a new Azure Mobile App Service instance which has been working fine. The only thing I can think that I've done to the server side configuration is add a Lets Encrpyt certificate to provide SSL support using the Lets Encrypt Azure Extension.
Now, when I publish, I get a Runtime Error. Looking in the Azure streaming logs, I can see the following every time I hit the application URL:

```
2017-06-29T13:54:07  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error</title> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error</h3> 
<h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
    <div id="details-left"> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetInitializationExceptionModule</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BeginRequest</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr>
```

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

OK< bit of an obscure and edge case one this, but thought I'd leave it here with the answer in case it helps someone.
I created the site and published it with it all working fine. I then changed the assembly name to fit in with my project naming standards and re-published, without selecting 'DELETE ALL FILES' becuase it would wipe out the Lets Encrypt extension settings. However, this lef the old DLL's hanging around in the \bin directory meaning there were two OWIN startup classes being found!

Deleting the old one fixed the issue.